# Angular7 only allow number input to accept 2 digit

Tags: html, angular

I've added `max="99"` and `maxlength="2"` on my number input, on keyboard arrow up it will cap on 99 but if user input the number using keyboard number button, they can input as much as they want. how can I prevent this from happening.

HTML :

```
<input matInput formControlName="vacancyCount" type="number" min="0" max="99" maxlength="2" placeholder="Vacancies" (keyup)="checkValue()" required>
```

TS :

```
checkValue(){
  // Prevent more that 2 digits
}
```

Comment: check the value any time the user presses a key or simply check for a change of value or check the value when you are submitting it.

Comment: Thanks for all the input, finally got my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have just provided only one line it is difficult to guess your project configurations but a Better approach to this would be custom validator with regex accepting two digits only because you can reuse the code

you can use this Regex

```
^[0-9]{1,2}?$
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check if value is greater than 99 set value to 99 or less than set value to 0 and just tell the user that "you can't add more than 99 or less than 0"

just do it manually

Answer (score 1):

You should use angular form validation. If user enters more that max or less than min value, show error.
[See this](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) for angular form validation guide.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this by using [`ngx-mask`](https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask#suffix-string) library.

```
<input type="text" mask="00" [validation]="true" />
```

[Stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nv21w5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)